.NET framework IIS Irregular Session Expiry
I have a website hosted on IIS and an SQL Server on a separate server. However, we're encountering sporadic session expiry issues when users navigate the website, leading to frequent logouts.
<sessionState 
   mode="SQLServer"
   allowCustomSqlDatabase="true"
   sqlConnectionString="Data Source=IP_ADDRESS;User Id=USER_ID;Password=USER_PASSWORD" 
   cookieless="false"
   timeout="35"/>

Additionaly, this is how the session is being set
 HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionIdentityKey] = identity;

Previously, the website was hosted on another server using SQL Express, where both IIS and SQL were on the same server. Since migrating to the current setup, we've been experiencing daily session expiry problems.
I've already adjusted recycling settings and advanced idle timeout settings, but the issue persists. I'm unsure which settings need adjustment or where to investigate further regarding session expiry.
Any insights on which settings to adjust or where to look further would be greatly appreciated. TIA!

For SQL based sessions, then session() should be rock solid, and even a app-pool restart still means session should remain intact. I would double, triple check that the session database on SQL is actually working. Remember, while a the ASPState database is created on the SQL server, the 2 tables to manage session are actually placed in the system tempdb. And in ASPState the stored procedures and routines in fact on SQL startup re-creates the 2 session tables in tempdb, not ASPState. So, I would double check if the ASPState database is installed correctly and check in tempdb for the 2 tables.

@AlbertD.Kallal I checked the ASPState, the [ASPStateTempApplications] and [ASPStateTempSessions] were created under ASPState, and not on system tempdb.... But I installed ASPState using aspnet_regsql.exe.

When  ASPState database is created, it installs a whole bunch of store procedures and all kinds of extra stuff. But keep in mind, those stored procedures and utilities in that database actually create the working tables in the system tempdb database. Not hinting, suggesting, or implying the ASPState database is to be installed or created anywhere else, but I am MOST certainly stating that the working tables that database uses are actually created in the tempdb database, not the ASPState one!  So, there are routines that run on database server startup - they create the working tables in tempdb

Check for the tables in the tempdb database - you should see and find them in that database. Perhaps this has changed, but from what I recall, the 2 working tables are created in tempdb, and as a result on database server restart, then the tables will not exist, but in the ASPState database, there are stored procedures marked to run ONE time on database server startup to re-create the 2 tables in tempdb.  I mean, do a query against the 2 tables you see in ASPState - do they have rows of data?
